# MongoDB: Is is possible to make sure to add a column to a document before inserting to a collection

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection named `products`. I want to make sure whenever a document in this collection is inserted or updated, I check if there is a `viewCount` field present or not. If it is, I let the `create/update` operation complete. Else, I want to add this field and set the value to zero.

The challenge is, there are a lot of such operations in the application code. So, I am looking for a way to accomplish this at DB level. Is this possible ?

Comment: can u please provide any reference ?

Comment: If you want to mandate a schema, are you sure you want to use MongoDB instead of a traditional relational DB?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: I understand your point but that's a topic for a separate discussion. Switching to another database is not an option in my case. I am asking the question in regards to an existing application which has been implemented in mongodb

Comment: Mongo is completely schema-less with no default values. If you want a schema (which generally includes default values), you're going to need to use your language's schema-enforcing ODM.

Answer (score -1):

Use [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/):

```js
db.products.findAndModify({
  query:{ yourQuery},
  update:{ fieldsToCreate, $inc: { viewCount:1} },
  new: true,
  upsert: true
})
```

where `fieldsToCreate` is a partial document of the values you want to create if the document does not exist. The new document will be returned with `viewCount` set to 1, which is correct, since it was viewed 1 time when returned.

Comment: It requires to change the query. I am looking for a way to accomplish this in a way that even if you write a simple insert query like `db.products.insert({"title": "some title"})`, the `viewCount` automatically gets attached to the document. It is possible by using an ORM. But I'm looking for a direction to implement this without using ORM since I want to leverage the performance of native driver and accomplish the goal with minimal changes to existing code

Comment: @mandeep_m91 It is not possible without an O**D**M (we are not talking of an relational database), and an ODM can not guarantee atomicity of view_count in any way. And btw: Downvoting as the OP without even bothering to explain why (only after request) is showing bad manners, to say the least. And once again: No triggers, no JOINS in MongoDB. I gave you a working solution and you honor it this way. Go find yourself.

Comment: Well, sorry about that then. I did not mean to offend you. I already knew such solution but was looking for a different route as I explained in my previous comment. Maybe I should have been more clear in my question about that. I cannot change my vote unless the answer is edited. So, if this entire scenario is reflecting bad practices and bad manners, please edit and I will take my vote back

Comment: anything.. just saying for removing the downvote. SO does not allow to remove a downvote unless the answer is edited.